# Store form data with file upload in an asset source using Freeform

Tags: assets, plugin-freeform

I currently have a form that has an upload file fieldtype and this currently stores the file in an asset source in Craft. What I would like to do is attach some of the form submitted field data alongside the asset using fields within the Asset field layout.

Ideally I would like to store the Form Submission ID, Name and Email address.

Any ideas as to how I would go about doing this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use Craft and/or freeform hooks https://solspace.com/craft/freeform/docs/events-and-hooks/#events-freeform-forms and fetch the assets related to the entry during the `beforeSave`process, add field values of the submission to it and save it again. There are examples how to do this in Crafts documentation

Or the most flexible (and for me easiest) thing: create a custom controller that extends the freeform controller and add a few lines to attach those information to the asset.

Comment: Thanks @RobinSchambach . Not my strong point so might have to get some assistance.

Comment: I never buyed freeform and I'm not going to do that. Unless you provide me access to your project I can't write the code because I don't it's exact structure. You have an examples how to use hooks here https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2934/5557. Here is the craft doc for how to use events https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/hooks-and-events#events Your code should look similar to those examples.